# displays only last image and text in a listview using base adapter in android

Tags: android, android-layout

In for loop it displaying only last data. In database how many rows are there so many rows are getting displayed by taking the last item
all the rows are taking last image and text
Now i want display all the images and text from the database in listview.please help me

```
enter code here
  public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static final Context Context = null;
String qrimage;
Bitmap bmp, resizedbitmap;
Activity activity = null;
private static LayoutInflater inflater;

private ImageView[] mImages;
String[] itemimage;
TextView[] tv;
String itemname;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ImageAdapter(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
    //inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  //  imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity);
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];

    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
            qrimage = image.getString("itemimage");
            itemname = image.getString("itemname");
            map.put("itemname", image.getString("itemname"));


            byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                    qrimageBytes.length);
            int width = 100;
            int height = 100;
            resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height,
                    true);

            mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
            mImages[i].setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

            mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);


            // tv[i].setText(itemname);
        }
        System.out.println(map);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}



public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View vi=convertView;

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);


       TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        text.setText(map.get("itemname"));

        return vi;


 }


}
```

Comment: `check length of  imageArrayJson.length()` and use `ViewHolder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line is going to store everything in one spot in the map:

```
map.put("itemname", image.getString("itemname"));
```

but perhaps you meant:

```
map.put(itemname, image.getString("itemname"));
```

also you have one field for `bmp` that gets reset each time through the loop. your `getView` method has a `position` parameter for a reason, so it can index into an array and find the appropriate information for that spot in the list. instead  your `getView` is retrieving the one `bmp` and the one `itemname` for the whole adapter instance -- not indexed by `position` as it ought to be.

I probably shouldn't be just giving you the code, but here it is.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  String qrimage;
  Bitmap bmp, resizedbitmap;
  Bitmap[] bmps;
  Activity activity = null;
  private LayoutInflater inflater;

  private ImageView[] mImages;
  String[] itemimage;
  TextView[] tv;
  String itemname;
  String[] itemnames;
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

  public ImageAdapter(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
    //inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //  imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity);
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.bmps = new Bitmap[imageArrayJson.length()];
    this.itemnames = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];

    try {

      for (int i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
        qrimage = image.getString("itemimage");
        itemname = image.getString("itemname");
        itemnames[i] = itemname;


        byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                                            qrimageBytes.length);
        int width = 100;
        int height = 100;
        resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height,
                                                  true);
        bmps[i] = bmp;

        mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
        mImages[i].setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

        mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);


        // tv[i].setText(itemname);
      }
      System.out.println(map);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO: handle exception
    }
  }

  public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
  }

  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }



  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View vi=convertView;

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);


    TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);
    text.setText(itemnames[position]);

    return vi;


  }


}
```

Comment: but i can print outside map it take only last value

Comment: how can i solve the above problem please edit my code and send to me

Comment: I've added the arrays to your original code, updated the answer.